# datepicker no longer displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I'm having two issues with the same aspect of my application, the abstract view is this:

The app allows users to view different video clips. On the back-end/admin section the admin can track the views of any particular group of clips. For example, the admin can choose `Universal Studios`, select a `date range: Beginning Date: 2015-01-1, End Date: 2016-01-1` and hit `filter`, and see the number of total views that `Universal` received within this range.

The problem is, for one, **datepicker** is no longer working, so when I click on the date fields, no calendar appears, I manually have to type in the date. And for two, I'm only getting results between furthest: `2015-10-18` and `2016-02-18`. When I type in `2015-09-18` or anything earlier it doesn't generate results.

Below is the error when I click inspect element in Chorme,

**error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined**

```
 */
 (function($) {
   var _datepicker = jQuery.fn.datepicker;

   $.fn.datepicker = function(options) {
    var $date = _datepicker.apply(this, arguments); <--- this line
```

**application.js requires**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/draggable
//= require jquery-ui/sortable
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require bootstrap
//= require carousel.js
//= require hover.js
//= require menu_js/modernizr.js
//= require menu_js/dlmenu.js
//= require custom.js
//= require bootstrap-tabs.js
//= require jquery.raty.js
//= require letsrate.js
//= require rails-timeago
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require scrollTo.js
//= require clips.js
//= require jquery.sticky.js
//= require jquery-ui.min.js
//= require jquery.dynatable.js
//= require playlist.js
//= require index.js.coffee
```

**index.html.erb snippit:**

```
<tr>
    <td><%= f.text_field :start_date, value: 1.month.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :end_date, value: Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %></td>
    <td>
      <%= f.submit "Filter", class: "btn btn-danger", data: {disable_with: 'Searching...'} %>
      <%= link_to 'Clear Form', '#', id: "clear", class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
    </td>
  </tr>
```